# Flutter Button design

Tags: flutter, dart

How do i make a design of button like this  ?

[image]

this is my current code

```
Container(
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
   child: RaisedButton(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Container(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                 gradient: new LinearGradient(colors: [
                     Color(0xFF00b09b),
                     Color(0xFF96c93d),
                  ])),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(
                      "ADD CREDITS",
                       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              )
           )
```

this is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the closest one I can do, without changing the **fontFamily**.
You may need to import a bold font to achieve the exact same effect.

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/12ba3e4ddd023a136bd3513c86e7c76b)

[image]

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap:(){},
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        colors: [
          Color(0xFF5FF20B),
          Color(0xFF3EA106),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        "ADD CREDITS",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          shadows: <Shadow>[
            Shadow(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 3.0),
              blurRadius: 3.0,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                 gradient: new LinearGradient(colors: [
                     Color(0xFF00b09b),
                     Color(0xFF96c93d),
                  ])),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(
                      "ADD CREDITS",
                       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
    ),
```